# C# best way how to parse this String

Tags: c#, regex, string

i have following problem: I have text like this (more than 200 lines):

> dsadsadsads(-123|12)sdakodskoakosdakodsadsayxvmyxcmxcym,§§¨§¨§(-43|23)sdadasdas

I want get numbers from text like this:

> -123|12
>
> -43|23

Numbers are always in `(` `)`.

What is the fast way, how to get this number. Is possible use some regex? How?

Or `brute force` `foor loop?`

Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Regex for this purpose.

```
string str = "dsadsadsads(-123|12)sdakodskoakosdakodsadsayxvmyxcmxcym,§§¨§¨§(-43|23)sdadasdas";
var matches = Regex.Matches(str, @"\(([-+]?\d+\|[-+]?\d+)\)");

foreach (var match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

Performance test

```
string str = "dsadsadsads(-123|12)sdakodskoakosdakodsadsayxvmyxcmxcym,§§¨§¨§(-43|23)sdadasdas";

StringBuilder bigstr = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    bigstr.Append(str + "\n");
}

str = bigstr.ToString();

Regex regex = new Regex(@"\(([-+]?\d+\|[-+]?\d+)\)");

Stopwatch w = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var matches = regex.Matches(str);
var count = matches.Count;
w.Stop();

Console.WriteLine(w.Elapsed);
```

Output in my console. about `0.001` seconds.

Comment: Are you sure using [`[-|+]`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b-%7c%2b%5d&i=%2b%0d%0a-%0d%0a%7c%0d%0aa%0d%0a)? That matches `+` and `-` of course but it also matches `|` what should not match. `[]` is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) Maybe this will work a little better because it cuts out the braces: [`(?<=\()[-+]?\d+\|[-+]?\d+(?=\))`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5c()%5b-%2b%5d%3f%5cd%2b%5c%7c%5b-%2b%5d%3f%5cd%2b(%3f%3d%5c))&i=(%2b42%7c34)%0d%0a)

Comment: duh! thanks for mentioning that. for a moment i thought thats `OR` i didnt noticed it later. @Verarind

Comment: Oh yes your regex captured the numbers in a group. Missread that. Sorry.